# Bulk HTTP Status Code Checker in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, cfhttp

How do i check the status codes of numerous urls. I know I can do something like this:

```
<cfloop from=1 to=10000 index="y">
 <cfhttp method="HEAD" url=... /> 
<cfloop>
```

However this is pretty slow mainly because the calls are synchronous. I would like to make the request asynchronous without putting to much stress on the server (*running* webserver).

Comment: Check this: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/749-learning-coldfusion-8-cfthread-part-ii---parallel-threads.htm

Comment: @Beginner This is exactly what i am looking for. However Ben codes example does not work on my server. The page/thread becomes unresponsive. I cannot even abort the request / thread in the server monitor.

Comment: What version of ColdFusion? If the URL is SSL, CF9 won't connect to the server at all. (I think CF10 has some issues w/newer certs too.)  Each request you make is going to use up a thread. Depending on the version of CF you are using, this could cause a problem.

Comment: I prefer to perform my checks using an offline program like Xenu Link Checker. http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html

Comment: Better SSL and multithreaded/asynchronous mode may be found using CFX_HTTP5.  http://adiabata.com/cfx_http5.cfm

Comment: @JamesMoberg The server is CF9. However i am using curl and not chttp. I didn't mention this because it is not relevant to the principle of the question.

Comment: @JamesMoberg is there a command line alternative voor xenulink?

Comment: @Nebu Using CURL w/CF9 is actually a better, SSL-compatible, thread-friendly, DNS-TTL-honoring solution than using CFHTTP. You could use CFExecute (or CRON) to process multiple URLs, save the status results to local file(s) and then use CURL to trigger CF to process the temp files. (You avoid potential time-outs & unresponsive CFthreads).

Comment: @Nebu regarding Xenu Link Checker w/command line, I don't think that functionality currently exists. I really wish it did. I'll contact the author of the program to request this feature.

Comment: @JamesMoberg I am not a big fan of cfthread in combination with cfexecute. In theory this should work great, however I have seen several situations where this combo causes serious problems. If Xenu Link goes command line i would really be interested.